# Hide Params on Profile.php and Enable slashes on pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

Let website link is www.abc.com I have 2 PHP Files.

home.php
profile.php

1. I want to remove .php and place slash on end
2. profile.php url (before - "www.abc.com/profile.php?id=no1") to "www.abc.com/user_name" (or "www.abc.com/abrar" or "www.abc.com/jahin" or "www.abc.com/piash" like this)
3. I want to add slashes also on profiles "www.abc.com/user_name/"

   I am currently using this htaccess config but when i put slahes on 
   www.abc.com/user_name it makes error

   ```
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /profile?uid=$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

I am using RAW PHP.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the URL `www.abc.com/profile.php?id=no1` is `no1` the `user_name` in the new URL?

Comment: Yes the no1 is the username @MrWhite